# employee - manager class diagram, representing additional constraints on manager entity

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram, model-associations

I come from an ER background and am shifting to UML diagrams. I am constructing an UML diagram for a real work scenario. One of the class diagram I am constructing is a Employee - Manager class diagram, where Manager is also an employee. This is a classic UML diagram that has been around for ages and it would be constructed like below

[image: Classic Employee-Manager class diagram]

However there are some things that a Manager can do but an Employee cannot, like a Manager can pay wages to (and only to) employees working under him/her. My solution to this situation is to reconstruct the class diagram like this

[image: Employee-Manager extended class diagram]

I am creating a specialized class for Manager and represent the relationship as third entity. Is this good ?

Comment: Do you need the EmployeeManagement entity?  You don't show any attributes on it other than foreign keys to Eee & Mgr.  If that's correct then you can just use a 1:M relationship from Mgr to Eee (which would translate to a FK in Eee pointing to Mgr). It's not wrong as it stands though, just not as concise as it could be. hth.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible types of relationships between Employee and Manager. 
You could expect that every manager is an employee. But is this true?
Is an interim manager for instance an employee? Or a subcontractor? Or a project manager from another organization? Same questions can be applied to employees.

Therefor is the classical relationship between employee and manager in many cases incorrect. An employee could have several roles in one organization. That happens in high schools or colleges, where some persons have educational contracts in different departments. One employee having different managers at different hours of the day.

Has a manager several employees in his department or actually a set of contracts? Could you describe a manager as an implementation of a certain function and being an employee a status having a valid contract within the organization? An organization might have 100 employees, 75 fte and 10 managers of which 2 work for different organizations.

The answer to your question is therefor: the chance that your model is correct is imo quite small. Very often is this relationship much more complex then your model can describe.